# TikZ drawing over plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot, layers

I would like to draw the red line over the plotted points. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
  ymin=0, ymax=4.75,
  xmin=0, xmax=14.5,
  grid,
  xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
  ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5},
 xlabel={Velocidad [rad/s]},
ylabel={Tensión DC [V]},
width=\textwidth, 
height=0.7\textwidth,
]
\addplot[only marks,mark size = 0.4pt,
  mark options={teal}] table[x=vel_dec, y=v_DC_dec,col sep=semicolon]{k_E_DCPM.csv};
\draw[red, ultra thick, domain=0.2997:12.5188] plot (\x,{0.321210875886567*\x});

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Tensión generada en terminales en función de la velocidad del rotor de la máquina DCPM}
\label{fig:k_E_DCPM}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the output I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please go back and accept and upvote the answers you already got for previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clip mode=individual` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=14.5,
ymin=0, ymax=4.75,
grid,
xtick distance=1, ytick distance=0.5,
xlabel={Velocidad [rad/s]},
ylabel={Tensión DC [V]},
clip mode=individual,
]
\addplot[teal, only marks]{0.33*x};
\draw[red, ultra thick, domain=0.2997:12.5188, samples=2] plot (\x,{0.321210875886567*\x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with red line on top of teal marks]

Comment: It worked. Thank you!